# How to Import Namespace on ASP.net Page

Tags: asp.net-3.5

I have created a Class named SearchableGridView in my App_Code directory.  I'm using

```
<Assembly: TagPrefix("MyApp.WebControls", "SearchGridView")> 
Namespace MyApp.WebControls
```

I have referenced it in web.config as:

```
<add namespace="MyApp.WebControls"/>
```

I have also included the following on my content page:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MyApp.WebControls" %>

<asp:SearchGridView ID="SearchGridView1" runat="server">
</asp:SearchGridView>
```

However, when I build the project, I receive the error: 
Warning 1   Element 'SearchGridView' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing.

How do I rectify this situation?

Thanks much for your help and guidance!

Comment: Is it a Web Site project or a Web Application project?

Comment: It is a web application project.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  It is actually a web site project.  Do I need to convert to a web application?