# Constants and web forms in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to now the best way to use constants in web forms for C# since im new to this, my constants are in a separate class and this is how i use them

```
    using Student.Scripts.Constants;

    namespace Student
    {
       public partial class masterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
       {
          protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
            testLabel.Text = Constant.APP_NAME;
          }
       }
    }
```

this writes what ever is in my constant to this label and it displays correctly, what i wanna know is this the right way, do you have to use a label every time, and what if i want to use the constant on the HTML  tag were i cant use a label, what then?

Comment: You can use your constant wherever you like from codebehind, it's just a string. If you want to access a html element from serverside you have to add `runat="server"` and an id.

Comment: Can you clarify your last statement on 'using in an HTML tag'?

Comment: if i want to use the constant in the following tags <@ @>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your constants are strings, you can use them anywhere you can use a string.

That includes the `Text` property of all controls.

Comment: but does this mean i need to use a label everywhere i want to use a constant, or can i use the constant as it is in <% %> tags

Comment: @Lappies - As I said, you can use it anywhere you can use a string. That includes in code blocks. `<%:Constant.APP_NAME%>` is fine.

Comment: this gives an error: CS0103: The name 'Constant' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Lappies - You may want to [import the namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256955/how-to-import-namespace-on-asp-net-page) that `Constant` is in.

Answer (score 0):

I would start practicing MVC with razor, so you won't have to take care of some of the complexity on client side and just use HTML tags to create your UX.

In case you need to have your constants on server side, you may have a static class to do so, like:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const string AppName = "MyApp";
    public const string AppVersion = "0.0.0.1";
}
```

As it was said before:

> Since your constants are strings, you can use them anywhere you can
>   use a string.
>
> That includes the Text property of all controls.